# display thumbnail wordpress in bootstrap popover

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, popover

How to display thumbnail wordpress in bootstrap popover?

I used `the_post_thumbnail` but this function inherently echo `<img>` . The resulting image is not shown in popover

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

/*********display the_post_thumbnail in data-content of popover *********/

echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="popover" data-title="'.get_the_title().'" data-content="'.the_post_thumbnail('full').'">';


the_title();
echo '</a>';
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `the_post_thumbnail()` inherently echoes the whole `<img>` tag, so it will do unexpected things when you echo it.  Do this instead:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="popover" data-title="'.get_the_title().'" data-content="';
the_post_thumbnail('full');
echo '">';
```

There's a very good chance that you'll now have issues with unescaped double-quotes in the `<img>` element that Wordpress will give you, so it might make more sense to just get the thumbnail URL:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' );
$url = $thumb['0'];


echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="popover" data-title="'.get_the_title().'" data-content="<img src=\''.$url.'\'>">';
```